# How to set html attributes to Django form created using model

Tags: python, html, django, forms, model

I have model

```py
class Listings(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And form class

```py
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'price', 'desc', 'img')
        labels = {
            'desc': 'Description',
            'img': 'Upload photo',
            'price': 'Starting price'
        }
```

I want to add HTML attributes like `min="0"` or **remove** `required` from my `img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')` for example. How can I implement this?

I found in stack overflow method with `widgets = {'price': IntegerField(attrs='min': 0})` and I also tried `...forms.IntegerField...` but I had

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

And I also found solution with

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Listings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['price'].widget.attrs.update({
        'min': 1
    })
```

(I added it to my form class)

But also did not work

```
super(Listings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
[05/Jan/2023 19:22:01] "GET /create_listing HTTP/1.1" 500 60691
```

Answer (score 1):

An [**`IntegerField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) is *not* a *widget*, but a *form field*. The default widget for an `IntegerField` is a [**`NumberInput`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput):

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'price', 'desc', 'img')
        labels = {
            'desc': 'Description',
            'img': 'Upload photo',
            'price': 'Starting price',
        }
        widget = {'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': 0})}
```

or you can work with:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['price'].widget.attrs['min'] = 1

    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'price', 'desc', 'img')
        labels = {
            'desc': 'Description',
            'img': 'Upload photo',
            'price': 'Starting price',
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I already found the solution by myself. `widget=forms.NumberInput` really was the solution

Answer (score 0):

In case it will be useful for someone. You should place (in my case)

```py
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    price = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'min': 0
        }))
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter your description',
        }))
    img = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={
            'id': 'img'
        }
    ))
    class Meta:
    # and code from question
```

And if you need to remove `required` from any field, you can add

```html
    <script>
        document.getElementById("img").required = false;
    </script>
```

To your `html` file